# Android - Spinner: text in several lines

Tags: android, text, spinner, checkedtextview, truncated

I have done the tutorial about Spinner ([[http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html]).](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) However, if the text is much longer than the names of the planets, after clicking the spinner the displayed text is truncated, it is not displayed in its entirety.

**Do anyone happen to know how to make the longer text to be displayed in several lines?**

After clicking the spinner texts are shown in the table of obejcts called CheckedTextViews. Maybe some preferences of those should be modificated - it is just the quick idea.

Will be glad for any support.

Answer (score 0):

This also works well.

```
<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="350dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView 
 android:id="@android:id/text1"
 style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:ellipsize="marquee"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:singleLine="false" />
</LinearLayout>
```